# C programming quiz based on datatypes

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 char c = 125;
 c = c+10;
 printf("%d", c);
 return 0;

}
```

Can any one please tell me why the output of the program is -121.
In advance thank you

Comment: When treated as a signed value, a char has the range -128 to 127.   When you added 10, it "overflowed" and became a negative value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C- why char c=129 will convert into -127?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756626/c-why-char-c-129-will-convert-into-127)

Comment: Also you want to see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47263865/is-signed-char-overflow-undefined-within-the-range-255-to-255#comment-81478565

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). Max char value is 127, the result of sum is 135 which is more